# Is there an app for a complete travel package deal?

Tags: package-holiday

There are many apps to find good deals on flights and hotels, such as Skyscanner, but what if there was an app that basically booked your entire trip for you, and could still offer deals?

That would mean transportation to the airport, flight, transportation from the airport, lodging with at least some meals provided, even a travel itinerary, and handling practicalities like getting you a public transport card and making sure you’d have cell phone service when there.

Is there a good app for that?

Comment: That's called a package holiday, and any bricks and mortar travel agency should be able to sort that out for you.  Most have websites these days, but these agencies are very local, so you'll need to tell us where you are for recommendations.

Comment: There are also several or even many online travel agencies but I would not be able to name one, not even in my own country.

Comment: Shopping recommendation questions are off topic - you could look at the Software Recommendation Stack Exchange, though - they may be able to help.